# g++ linking undefined reference even though my shared object has those methods

Tags: compilation, linker, g++, shared-objects

Edit: Answer found.  Ignore

Sorry to ask this question even though it's been asked so many times but I've checked like 20+ similar questions and none of them have helped.

I've created a shared object and am now using it in a program that links to that .so.  The program is not able to link (ld error).

**memfxns.h:**

```
#ifndef MEM_H
#define MEM_H
char* getBuf();
void releaseBuf(char*);
#endif
```

**memfxns.cpp:**

```
#include "memfxns.h"

char* getBuffer()
{
        char* ret_val = new char[4];
        //fill the buffer here
        return ret_val;
}

void releaseBuffer(char* buf)
{
        delete buf;
}
```

These guys are compiled like so to produce a shared object (note I've tried without the -soname because it appears to be repetitive, but did not succeed):

```
g++ -Wall -fPIC -c ./*.cpp
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libmemfxns.so -o ./libmemfxns.so ./*.o
```

Now I want to get my program to link against the new .so:

**prog.cpp:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "memfxns.h"

int main()
{
        char* buf = getBuf();
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                printf("%d\n", buf[i]);
        releaseBuf(buf);

        return 0;
}
```

Which I compile using the command:

```
g++ ./prog.cpp -o prog -I/home/jbu/Desktop/hadooprelated/testjna/so/include -L/home/jbu/Desktop/hadooprelated/testjna/so -lmemfxns
/tmp/ccOR12i1.o: In function `main':
prog.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `getBuf()'
prog.cpp:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `releaseBuf(char*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I'm fairly sure that it's able to find libmemfxns.so because when I purposely call -lmemfxnsdoesntexist it complains that it cannot find the .so.  I'm also sure my -L and -I directories are correct.

I'm not sure if I need some kind of namespace/scoping in my header file but I have not seen examples need that...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
-Julian

Answer (score 3):

Wow look at this idiot, he has the methods named differently in the header compared to how they're named in the .cpp.

Comment: Insulting someone is rarely helpful. Insulting yourself is probably ok, though I'd phrase it differently.